# c++ - store byte[4] in an int

Tags: c++, int, byte, type-conversion

I want to take a byte array with 4 bytes in it, and store it in an int.

For example (non-working code):

```
unsigned char _bytes[4];
int * combine;
_bytes[0] = 1;
_bytes[1] = 1;
_bytes[2] = 1;
_bytes[3] = 1;
combine = &_bytes[0];
```

I do not want to use bit shifting to put the bytes in the int, I would like to point at the bytes memory and use them as an int if possible.

Comment: No you cannot. Endianness is unknown and only bit shift can guarantee

Comment: Well, if you *want to determine* the endianness of the host system at run-time, then this can be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Standard C++ it's not possible to do this reliably. The strict aliasing rule says that when you read through an expression of type `int`, it must actually designate an `int` object (or a `const int` etc.) otherwise it causes undefined behaviour.

However you can do the opposite: declare an `int` and then fill in the bytes:

```
int combine;
unsigned char *bytes = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&combine);
bytes[0] = 1;
bytes[1] = 1;
bytes[2] = 1;
bytes[3] = 1;

std::cout << combine << std::endl;
```

Of course, *which* value you get out of this depends on how your system represents integers. If you want your code to use the same mapping on different systems then you can't use memory aliasing; you'd have to use an equation instead.

Comment: Notably, this also avoids any alignment problems.

Comment: This works perfect as you can modify `combine` and by doing so will also change values in the individual bytes. Thank you.